# Why is Svelte throwing a "Not Found" requiring +layout.svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

My svelte project has a number of nested routes under the `routes` folder but it seems that whenever I don't add the `+layout.svelte` in each folder it complains with the following:

```
Error: Not found: /admin/organisations/1/passes/+layout.svelte
    at resolve (/Users/phil/reps/myclasspass-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:483:13)
    at resolve (/Users/phil/reps/myclasspass-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:285:5)
    at Object.handle (/Users/phil/reps/myclasspass-frontend/src/hooks.server.js:57:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Module.respond (/Users/phil/reps/myclasspass-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:282:20)
    at async file:///Users/phil/reps/myclasspass-frontend/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:505:22
```

Firstly is `+layout.svelte` required in each folder? Second, in this instance, the route `/admin/organisations/1/passes/+layout.svelte` actually has a `+layout.svelte` file. It seems that sometimes it's reporting it's missing the layout file even though it might be missing out of another folder in my app. In any event it's annoying due to the number of error messages that get reported every time a route is loaded or reloaded.

UPDATE:

Ok I have been able to narrow this down to something styles related. When I use the following in my `+layout.svelte` the stack trace per above shows.

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import '../assets/scss/preloader.css';
    @import "../assets/scss/themes.css";
</style>
```

If I delete these imports the problem goes away albeit my styles aren't being imported. I changed it to import these CSS files from within the <"script"> tag and now the error has changed.

```
Error: Not found: /admin/organisations/1/themes.css
```

and

```
Error: Not found: /admin/organisations/1/themes.css.map
```

These errors are thrown when I'm on that route. It seems to be importing the CSS fine though so not sure why it's reporting it cant find the files. The files are located in `src/assets/scss`

Comment: `+layout.svelte` isn't needed. e.g. see the tutorial before you add the layout, https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/layouts. What code is running at `myclasspass-frontend/src/hooks.server.js:57:28`

Comment: There's actually nothing on line 57 of my hooks. It only goes to line 54. In fact none of the logged lines in the stack trace are matching up to the actual files.

Comment: There should not be layout missing errors as long as you have  a root layout (directly in `routes`).

Comment: I do have +layout.svelte in `src/routes/+layout.svelte` which has a <slot/> and renders correctly. The app behaves correctly but it's continually pushing out the error as per above.

Comment: Would need minimal repo to help. In a vacuum, the only thing I can think of is svelte not liking a folder with a number as a name

Comment: Ok I have been able to narrow this down to something styles related. When I use the following in my `+layout.svelte` the stack trace per above shows.
```
<style lang="scss">
    @import '../assets/scss/preloader.css';
    @import "../assets/scss/themes.css";

    .hide {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```
I changed it to import these CSS files from within the <script> tag and now the error has changed. `Error: Not found: /admin/organisations/1/themes.css` and `Error: Not found: /admin/organisations/1/themes.css.map`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install `svelte-preprocess` and in your `svelte.config` add these lines:

```js
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
```

```js
preprocess: preprocess({
        scss: {}
    }),
```

just after the

```js
const config = {...
```

block

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. I already had the pre-processor installed, although I hadn't specified `scss`. I tried adding that but it's still coming up as missing the CSS and map files.

Comment: What I do not understand is why are you mixing CSS and SCSS in the first place. 

How about to do *this* in the root `+layout.svelte`

<script>
import '../assets/scss/preloader.css';
import '../assets/scss/themes.css':

//rest of your code if you have any 
</script>

Comment: Also the pre-processor needs to be from `svelte-preprocess` not from vite

Comment: I had to use CSS due to having purchased a theme which is written in SCSS as global styles. As it's currently a huge dependency tree due to providing every icon under the sun it was taking forever to rebuild, so it was easier to separate those styles out. With regard to the error, the issue is the relative paths. I have a route which is routes/admin/organisations/[organisationId]/clients/[clientId]/+page.svelte. As it's loading the CSS relative to the current page in the organisations route, [clientId] is being replaced with "themes.css" instead of the ID which is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I am experiencing is caused by the generated CSS from SASS. When generating CSS from SASS, the last line in the generated CSS is

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=themes.css.map */
```

I'm importing the CSS as follows in the main +layout.svelte

```html
<style lang="css">
    @import '/css/themes.css';
</style>
```

The thing that was super confusing for me was why it was only happening intermittently. The issue was only happening when my Chrome debugger window was open. Close the debugger and it doesn't attempt to load the source mappings per the last line of the CSS file.

This then somehow triggers another get against the endpoint to retrieve +layout.svelte. This feels somewhat buggy to me as you should be able to load source mappings in a CSS file, but the easy fix is to remove the source mappings.